# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have TensorFlow installed of version 1.14.0 on my Ubuntu machine. I am trying to run a code with

```
import keras
```

and I get an error

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'backend'
```

Complete Traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/**init**.py",
> line 3, in 
> from . import utils
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/**init**.py",
> line 6, in 
> from . import conv_utils
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py",
> line 3, in 
> from .. import backend as K
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/**init**.py",
> line 83, in 
> from .tensorflow_backend import *
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
> line 1, in                                       import
> tensorflow as tf
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 28, in 
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint:
> disable=unused-import
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
> line 63, in                                            from
> tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint:
> disable=redefined-builtin
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py",
> line 25, in                             from
> tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 54, in                                       from
> tensorflow.python.platform import app
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
> line 23, in                                        from
> absl.app import run as _run
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
> line 35, in 
> import pdb
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 76, in 
> import code
> File "/home/amitbhanja/RL-Deployment/Training/code.py", line 8, in
>
> from keras.optimizers import Adam
> File
> "/home/amitbhanja/python-environments/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py",
> line 11, in 
> if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
> AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'backend'

I have tried installing specific version of Keras (2.0.8) because I have seen an answer which says Keras 2.0.8 is required for TensorFlow 1.14.0 . But still I get the error.

Comment: you are installing old version of keras. try installing `keras 2.3`

Comment: getting the same error with `keras 2.3`

Comment: you have a file named code.py which seems to interfere with an imports in pdb.py, rename that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a file in your codebase that interferes with python's own modules, this file is `code.py` and is being imported inside a system file (`pdb.py`), rename your `code.py` to something else and it will probably solve the issue.